# Decomposition of variance in linear regression, normality

Tags: regression, least-squares, normality-assumption

Please correct me if I am mistaken, but I've read somewhere that the usefulness of **normally** distributed errors $e$ lies in the fact that we use independence to decompose
$$
Var(y) = Var(y - \hat y + \hat y) = Var(\hat y) + Var(y - \hat y)
$$
Or, to put it differently
$$
Var(\hat e) = Var(y - \hat y) = Var(y) - Var(\hat y)
$$
The question is: to me, the first property is simply a consequence of OLS method, as we assume that $\hat e$ is independent of the explanatory variables, as they are orthogonal. So how does normality help here?

Comment: These are purely variance calculations, so they only require assumptions of zero covariance.